# Checkbox field immediately gets unchecked after checking in Angular/Ionic app

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I have a series of data that I am looping through in my app. Each item contains the field `checked` that represents whether or not the checkbox for that item should be checked. By default, that is set to `checked: false` in my `list.html` file.

```
<ion-item lines="full" *ngFor="let item of items">
    <ion-label [class.strike]="item.checked" class="ion-padding ion-text-wrap">
        {{ item.title }}
    </ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox slot="start" [(ngModel)]="item.checked" mode="ios" (ionChange)="itemChecked(item)"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
```

On change of the checkbox being selected using the `ionChange`, I call my `itemChecked` method pass my `item` to it.

```
async itemChecked(item: Item) {
    console.log(item); //I can see checked has been updated.
    await this.firestore.updateItemKey(item, 'checked');
}
```

Then, in my `firestore` service file, I update the document like so:

```
updateItemKey(item: Item, key: string) {
    const itemDocRef = doc(this.firestore, `items/${item.id}`);
    return updateDoc(itemDocRef, { key: item[key] });
}
```

However, back in my `list.html` file, the item is not being checked and nothing is being correctly updated in my firebase database? The item quickly shows as checked then immediately goes back to unchecked.

Any thoughts on what I may have overlooked or done incorrectly that is causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `[(ngModel)]="item.checked"` I think you should just go with `[checked]="item.checked"`, and in `itemChecked()` do `item.checked = !item.checked` because you'd want to update the [checked] binding with new value. Of course, you should handle checked==false result of ionChange too.

Comment: Thank you this was helpful and got me going in a better direction. Can you elaborate more on what you mean by the handling of `checked==false` in `ionChange`?

Comment: Well you're updating the firebase with 'checked', but the ionChange can also be triggered by unchecking the checkbox, and thus you'd again update with 'checked'.

Comment: I think I am following. I basically want to capture whatever the current value of `checked` is for the item and save that in firebase.

Comment: Yes, sorry, you're probably right, I'm not much into firebase.

Comment: No worries. This is my first time using it. I appreciate the insight and pointers. Marked as accepted answer.